# Started over 200 threads, but only got around 20 active threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

The problem troubled me for whole day was I started around 200 threads, each thread will call the method which will call webservice inside the method.

When I opened the TCPView, I can only see around 20 connection between the client Process to WCF server.

I am not intended to use the PLINQ or ThreadPool, as each thread may take long time to calculate then return,

My Client thread part of codes is like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(InnerCalculate));
    t.Start(new ThreadParameter()
        {
            Index = i,
            Count = inputs.Count
        });

    threads.Add(t);
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}

foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

the Service side configuration of Behavior is as :

```
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentInstances="6"/>
    </behavior>
```

Can anyone tell me where I was wrong? or the problem may happens on where? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that the other end is preventing more than 20 simultaneous connections from the same IP?

Comment: Please show the code that makes the connection.

Comment: Could also be .NET limiting the connections.

Comment: There is also the limit of two client connections to each server IP enforced by the client itself. 
BTW, you can easily specify that a task is a long-running one

Comment: by default .net allow only a few no of consecutive connections to port 80 of any server but you can the configuration explicitly.

Comment: Take a look [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41aa5f44-ead6-47ba-8bd7-c918c9f0aee0/wcf-any-limit-of-threads-in-a-service-call](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41aa5f44-ead6-47ba-8bd7-c918c9f0aee0/wcf-any-limit-of-threads-in-a-service-call) at lastest post

Comment: This is crying out for something other than threads. Threads are heavyweight in the world of multi-threaded programming. But then I guess this depends on the hardware.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - Yes, the typical .NET solution for long running asynchronous I/O would be to use I/O Completion Ports.

Comment: @mbeckish Depends if there are 200 cores to run those threads on :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Even if you had 200 cores, why tie them up for a long time waiting for I/O?  Why not use IOCP?

Comment: @mbeckish I agree, I'm more coming from the avenue that 200 threads will grind the hardware to a halt on most standard desktops, but a server should cope (as opposed to the argument that threads are more wasteful than alternatives). That said they are still not ideal regardless of hardware in the face of other options.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if there is a limit of two client connection for each server IP, how could i Break this limit????

Answer (score 1):

Is this not just WCF throttling the number of concurrent connections available? Your measurement of 20 is only an indirect indication of what's going on, chances are you really do have the full 200 threads but only 20 can connect at a time.

Comment: Do connections to WCF use [ServicePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx)?

Comment: I don't think it's a throtting problem, as i set the throtting to max 6 each server, i have 9 servers, so there might be 54 connection allowed to the server, but not 20.

Comment: I searched the client side and server side solution, no word ConnectionLimit existed.

Comment: @robin.lo - Are you sure it is 20 connections, or could it be 18?  If so, then that would fit with the default 2 connections per destination limit on the client side.

Comment: @robin.lo - There is a default - it might not be set explicitly in your code.

Comment: @mbeckish You are smart guy!! When i used to use PLINQ, i noticed there are 18 connection and 2 for each server. it seems the client side job process still connect no more than 2 connection for each server, why was that happens?!??

Comment: @robin.lo - Follow my link above to ServicePoint.